# Android JNI: how to do reverse debugging?

Tags: android, debugging, android-ndk, gdb, java-native-interface

Is there any way to do reverse debugging in a native (c++) Android app?

Specifically, I need to be able to call `record` and `reverse-continue` with gdb, to find the cause of a memory corruption (as instructed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9771720/1054746).

Right now, the `record` and `reverse-continue` commands just print something like "the platform does not support that command".

Answer (score 0):

On Android, `reverse-continue` should only work for you if you debug on one of the `Intel x86 System Image` platforms (available from the SDK Manager).

See the [GDB Documentation:](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/news/reversible.html)

> Presently, only certain target debugging environments will support
>   reverse debugging. Those targets currently include:
>
> - Native i386-linux ('target record')
> - Native amd64-linux ('target    record')
> - Several remote targets, including:
>
>   - moxie-elf simulator
>   - Simics
>   - VMware Workstation 7.0
>   - the SID simulator (xstormy16 architecture)
>   - chronicle-gdbserver using valgrind
>   - UndoDB

Comment: I think that page is old. On http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/ProcessRecord it says that arm-linux is supported.